# Prove that these four definition of $T_{3{\frac 1 2}}$ space are equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, separation-axioms

> **Definition**
>
> A subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ is a zero-set if there exist a continuous real valued function $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb R$ such that
> $$
> Y=f^{-1}[0]
> $$
> So we say that a subset $Z$ of $X$ is cozero-set if $X\setminus Z$ is zero-set.

So we observe that a zero set is closed whereas a cozero-set is open and moreover the finite intersection or finite union of zero-set or cozero-set is a zero-set or a cozero-set respectively. Finally, we observe that the sets
$$
\{x\in X:f(x)>a\}\quad\text{and}\quad\{x\in X:a<f(x)<b\}\quad\text{and}\quad\{x\in X:f(x)<b\}
$$
are cozero-sets.

So we let give this definition.

> **Definition**
>
> A topological space $X$ is said completely regular if for any closed $C$ and for any $x\notin C$ there exists a continuous function $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that
> $$
> f(x)=0\quad\text{and}\quad f[C]\subseteq{1}
> $$

However it is a well know result that $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to any other intervals $[a,b]$ between a function $\varphi$ such that
$$
\varphi(0)=b\quad\text{and}\quad \varphi(1)=a
$$
so that we observe that $X$ is completely regular if and only if for any for any closed set $C$ and for any $x\notin C$ there exists a continuous function $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that
$$
f(x)=b\quad\text{and}\quad f(x)=a
$$

Now we give the following definition

> **Definition**
>
> A space $X$ is said $T_{3_{\frac 1 2}}$ if it is $T_1$ and completely regular.

So I tried to prove the following relevant result.

> **Theorem**
>
> For any $T_1$ space $X$ the following four statement are equivalent.
>
> 1. $X$ is $T_{3_{\frac 1 2}}$
> 2. the collection $C([0,1]^X)$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$ generates the topology on $X$, that is the collection
>    $$
>    \mathcal S:=\big\{f^{-1}[V]: f\in C([0,1]^X)\quad\text{and}\quad V\,\text{open in }[0,1]\big\}
>    $$
>    is a subbase for $X$.
> 3. the collection of **co**zero-sets is a base for $X$
> 4. there exists a base $\mathcal B$ such such that
>
> > 4.1. for any open basic neighborhood  $B_x$ of $x\in X$ there exists a basic open $B$ **disjoint** from $x$ and such that
> > $$
> > B_x\cup B=X
> > $$
> >
> > 4.2. for any pair $B_1$ and $B_2$ of basic open set there exists another pair $A_1$ and $A_2$ of basic open and **disjoint** set such that
> > $$
> > X\setminus B_1\subseteq A_1\quad\text{and}\quad X\setminus B_2\subseteq A_2
> > $$
>
> *Proof*.
>
> 1. So if $A$ is an open set of $X$ then $X\setminus A$ is closed and so for any $x\in A$ there exists  $f\in C([0,1]^X)$ such that
>    $$
>    f(x)=1\quad\text{and}\quad f[X\setminus A]\subseteq\{0\}
>    $$
>    that is such that
>    $$
>    f(x)=1\quad\text{and}\quad X\setminus A\subseteq f^{-1}[0]
>    $$
>    so that we conclude that
>    $$
>    x\in f^{-1}\big[(0,1]\big]=f^{-1}\big[[0,1]\setminus\{0\}\big]=f^{-1}\big[[0,1]\big]\setminus f^{-1}[0]=X\setminus f^{-1}[0]\subseteq A
>    $$
>    which proves that the collection
>    $$
>    \big\{f^{-1}\big[(0,1]\big]:f\in C([0,1]^X)\big\}
>    $$
>    is a base for $X$ and so the statement follows observing that
>    $$
>    \big\{f^{-1}\big[(0,1]\big]:f\in C([0,1]^X)\big\}\subseteq\cal S
>    $$
> 2. First of all we observe that the inclusion
>    $$
>    C([0,1]^X)\subseteq C(\Bbb R^X)
>    $$
>    holds and thus by above observed for any $f\in C([0,1]^X)$ the set
>    $$
>    f^{-1}\big[(\epsilon,1]\big]
>    $$
>    with $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ is a cozero-set: thus clearly the statement follows proving that if $A$ is open then for any $x\in A$ there exists $f\in C([0,1]^X)$ such that
>    $$
>    x\in f^{-1}\big[(\epsilon,1]\big]\subseteq A
>    $$
>    So if $C([0,1]^X)$ generates the topology on $X$ then for any $x_0\in A$ there exists $f\in C([0,1]^X)$ and open basic $B$ of $[0,1]$ such that
>    $$
>    x_0\in f^{-1}[B]\subseteq A
>    $$
>    and thus we distinguish the case where
>    $$
>    y_0:=f(x_0)
>    $$
>    is zero from the case where it is not.
>    $$
>    \bf{ CASE\,I}\\y_0=0
>    $$
>    So if $y_0$ is zero then without loss of generality we suppose that
>    $$
>    B=[0,\epsilon)
>    $$
>    for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ so that we observe that the position
>    $$
>    \varphi(y):=1-y
>    $$
>    for any $y\in [0,1]$ defines a homeomorphism $\varphi$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ such that
>    $$
>    \varphi^{-1}\big[(1-\epsilon,1]\big]=[0,\epsilon)
>    $$
>    and thus we conclude that $\varphi\circ f$ is a continuous function from $X$ to $[0,1]$ such that
>    $$
>    x_0\in(\varphi\circ f)^{-1}\big[(1-\epsilon,1]\big]\subseteq A
>    $$
>    $$
>    \bf CASE\, II\\ y_0\neq 0
>    $$
>    If $y_0$ is not zero then we distinguish the following two cases
>
> i.$B=B(y_0,\epsilon):=(y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$
>
> > First of all we observe that the positions
> > $$
> > \text{a. }f_1(y):=\frac y{y_0}
> > \\
> > \text{b. }f_2(y):=\frac{1-y}{1-y_0}
> > $$
> > for any $y\in\Bbb R$ define two continuous functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ so that we observe that the position
> > $$
> > \varphi(y):=\begin{cases}f_1(y),\quad\text{if }y\le y_0\\
> > f_2(y),\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> > $$
> > for any $y\in[0,1]$ define a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ - with respect the subspace topology.
> > Now put
> > $$
> > \varepsilon:=\max\big\{\varphi(y_0-\epsilon),\varphi(y_0+\epsilon)\big\}
> > $$
> > and thus we let to prove that
> > $$
> > \varphi^{-1}\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]\subseteq B(y_0,\epsilon)
> > $$
> > First of all we observe that
> > $$
> > \varphi^{-1}\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]=f^{-1}_1\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]\cup f^{-1}\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]
> > $$
> > where $f^{-1}_i$ for $i=1,2$ is restriced to $[0,1]$, the domain of $\varphi$: so the statement follows proving that
> > $$
> > f^{-1}_i\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]\subseteq B(y_0,\epsilon)
> > $$
> > for $i=1,2$. So we observe that $f_1$ is strictly increasing (and thus injective too) so that the inequality
> > $$
> > y_0-\epsilon\le f^{-1}_1(\varepsilon)\le y_0
> > $$
> > holds and thus we conclude that
> > $$
> > f^{-1}\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]\subseteq (y_0-\epsilon,y_0]\subseteq B(y_0,\epsilon)
> > $$
> > However we observe that $f_2$ is strictly decreasing (and thus injective too) so that the inequality
> > $$
> > y_0\le f^{-1}_2(\varepsilon)\le y_0+\epsilon
> > $$
> > holds and thus we conclude that
> > $$
> > f^{-1}_2\big[(\varepsilon,1]\big]\subseteq [y_0,y_0+\epsilon)\subseteq B(y_0,\epsilon)
> > $$
>
> ii.$B=(\epsilon, 1]$ with $\epsilon\in(0,1)$
>
> > In this case $f^{-1}[B]$ is trivially a cozero neighborhood of $x_0$.
>
> 3. Now let be $Z_f$ the set of zero points for any $f\in C(\Bbb R^X)$ whereas let be $Z_f^*$ its complement and thus finally let be $\cal Z^*$ the collection of this such sets which now we assume is a base so that we let to prove that it satisfies $4.1$ and $4.2$.
>
> > 4.1 Well, if $x_0$ is an element of any $Z^*_f$ then putting
> > $$
> > y_0:=f(x_0)
> > $$
> > we observe that the position
> > $$
> > \varphi(y):=y_0-y
> > $$
> > for any $y\in\Bbb R$ defines a continuous function so that also $\varphi\circ f$ is continuous. So observing that
> > $$
> > (\varphi\circ f)(x)=y_0\neq 0
> > $$
> > for any $x\in Z_f$ we conclude that
> > $$
> > Z_f\subseteq Z^*_{\varphi\circ f}
> > $$
> > that is
> > $$
> > Z^*_f\cup Z^*_{\varphi\circ f}=X
> > $$
> > Moreover we observce that
> > $$
> > (\varphi\circ f)(x_0)=0
> > $$
> > that is
> > $$
> > x_0\notin Z^*_{\varphi\circ f}
> > $$
> > So $\mathcal Z^*$ satisfies $4.1$.
> >
> > 4.2 So we observe that if any $Z^*_{f_1}$ and $Z^*_{f_2}$ are disjoint when their union is $X$ then $\cal Z^*$ satisfies $4.2$ trivially so that  we suppose there exists a not disjoint pair $Z^*_{f_1}$ and $Z^*_{f_2}$  whose union is $X$. So in this case we pick $x_0$ in $Z^*_{f_1}\cap Z^*_{f_2}$ and thus we observe that the positions
> > $$
> > \text{a. }\varphi_1(x):=\min\big\{f_1^2(x)-f^2_2(x),0\big\}
> > \\
> > \text{b. }\varphi_2(x):=\max\big\{f_1^2(x)-f_2^2(x),0\big\}
> > $$
> > for any $x\in X$ define two continuous functions $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ so that we let to prove that $Z^*_{\varphi_1}$ and $Z^*_{\varphi_2}$ are two disjoint open set containg $Z_{f_1}$ and $Z_{f_2}$ respectively. So we observe that if $\varphi_1(x)$ is not zero for any $x\in X$ then $\varphi_2(x)$ is zero and vice versa so that $X$ is union of $Z_{\varphi_1}$ and of $Z_{\varphi_2}$ and thus finally
> > $$
> > Z_{\varphi_1}^*\cap Z_{\varphi_2}^*=(X\setminus Z_{\varphi_1})\cap(X\setminus Z_{\varphi_2})=X\setminus(Z_{\varphi_1}\cup Z_{\varphi_2})=X\setminus X=\emptyset
> > $$
> > After all, $X$ is union of $Z_{f_1}^*$ and of $Z_{f_2}^*$ so that $Z_{f_1}$ and $Z_{f_2}$ are disjoint an thus $\varphi_i$ is not zero in $Z_{f_1}$ for $i=1,2$, that is
> > $$
> > Z_{f_1}\subseteq Z^*_{\varphi_i}
> > $$
>
> 4. So if $C$ is a closed set then $X\setminus C$ is open and thus for any $x_0\in X\setminus C$ there exists a basic open set $U$ such that
>    $$
>    x\in U\subseteq X\setminus C
>    $$
>    Nowe by assumption there exists a basic open set $V$ **disjoint** form $x$ and such that
>    $$
>    U\cup V=X
>    $$
>    Moreover by assumption there exists two basic **disjoint** open set $A$ and $V$ such that
>    $$
>    X\setminus U\subseteq B\quad\text{and}\quad X\setminus V\subseteq A
>    $$
>    So we observe that
>    $$
>    x_0\in X\setminus V\subseteq A\quad\text{and}\quad F\subseteq X\setminus U\subseteq B
>    $$
>    and moreover if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $X$ is union of $X\setminus A$ and $X\setminus B$. So with these achievements we put
>    $$
>    f(x):=\begin{cases}0,\quad\text{if }x\in A\\
>    \frac 1 2,\quad\text{if }x\in (X\setminus A)\cap (X\setminus B)\\
>    1,\quad\text{if }x\in B\end{cases}
>    $$
>    for any $x$ and thus we let to that the last position defines a continuous function.

So as you can see I was not able to prove that the statement $4$ implies the statement $1$ so that I thought to put a specific question where additionally I asked if the proof of the first three statement are correct: in particular I tried to use the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) to prove the continuity of $f$ but unfortunately it seem not work now. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Other names for zero-set and co-zero set are functionally closed set and functionally open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we prove:

> If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space an $M_k := \lbrace \frac{l}{2^k} : l = 0, \ldots, 2^k\rbrace$,$k \in
>  \mathbb{N}_0$ and $M := \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=0}M_k$.
> Furthermore if there exists a function, which assigns every $r \in M$
> a set $O_r \in \mathcal{T}$ such that if $r,s \in M$ and $r < s$ then
> $\overline{O_r} \subseteq O_s$ and $O_0 = \emptyset,O_1 = X$ follows.
> Under these conditions  \begin{equation} f : \begin{cases} X \to [0,1]
>  \\ x \mapsto \inf \lbrace r \in M : x \in O_r \rbrace \end{cases}
>  \end{equation} is continuous.

Proof:
Obviously from $O_1 = X$ it follows that $\lbrace r \in M : x \in O_r \rbrace$ for $x \in X$ is never empty and therefore from $M \subseteq [0,1]$ we get that $f$ is well defined. Similarly from $O_0 = \emptyset$ follows that $\lbrace r \in M : x \in \overline{O_r}^C \rbrace \neq \emptyset$ hence
\begin{equation}
g : \begin{cases}
X \to [0,1] \\
x \mapsto \sup \lbrace r \in M : x \in \overline{O_r}^C \rbrace
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is well defined. For $s \in \lbrace r \in M : x \in \overline{O_r}^C \rbrace$ and $t \in \lbrace r \in M : x \in O_r \rbrace$ where $x \in X$ is fixed we get $s < t$ otherwise $x \in \overline{O_s}^C \cap O_t \subseteq \overline{O_s}^C \cap O_s = \emptyset$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $g(x) \leq f(x)$ for $x \in X$. If there exists $x \in X$ such that $g(x) \leq f(x)$ then [from the density of $M$ in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468707/how-to-show-that-that-dyadic-rational-are-dense-in-r) one gets $r,s \in M$ such that $g(x) < r < s < f(x)$. Since $\overline{O_r} \subseteq O_s$ which implies $x \in O_s$ or $x \in O_s^C \subseteq \overline{O_r}^C$ hence $f(x) \leq s$ or $g(x) \geq r$, contradiction. Therefore $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. The continuity of $f : X \to [0,1]$ is equivalent to the continuity of $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ since the subspace topology on $[0,1]$ is the initial topology and $f$ is continous iff $\iota \circ f$ is continuous, where $\iota : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the canonical embedding. Also it is enough to show that the preimages of a subbasis of the euclidian topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are in $\mathcal{T}$. For this we choose the sets $(-\infty, t),(t, +\infty)$,$t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \inf \lbrace r \in M : x \in O_r \rbrace < t \iff \exists r \in M, r < t : x \in O_r \iff x \in \bigcup_{\substack{r \in M \\ r < t}}O_r, \\
g(x) &= \sup \lbrace r \in M : x \in \overline{O_r}^C\rbrace > t \iff \exists r \in M, r > t : x \in \overline{O_r}^C \iff x \in \bigcup_{\substack{r \in M \\ r > t}}\overline{O_r}^C.
\end{align}
From this $f^{-1}(-\infty,t) = \bigcup_{\substack{r \in M \\ r < t}}O_r \in \mathcal{T}$ and $f^{-1}(t,+\infty) = \bigcup_{\substack{r \in M \\ r > t}}\overline{O_r}^C \in \mathcal{T}$ follows hence $f$ is continuous.

Now we use this to proof:

> If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{B} \subseteq
> \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a normal basis, then two disjoint sets $A,B \in
>  \mathcal{B}^C = \lbrace B^C : B \in \mathcal{B} \rbrace$ can be
> separated by a continuous function $f : X \to [0,1]$, i.e. $f(A)
>  \subseteq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$,$f(B) \subseteq \lbrace 1 \rbrace$.

Proof: Since $\mathcal{B}$ is normal there exists $G_0,H_0 \in \mathcal{B} : G_0 \supseteq A$,$H_0 \supseteq B$ and $G_0 \cap H_0 = \emptyset$. Set $H_1 := \emptyset$ and $G_1 := B^C \supseteq H^C_0 \supseteq \overline{G_0}$ then
$G_1 \in \mathcal{B}$. Then from this definitions for $k = 0$ we have
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:simple}
\forall \zeta,\xi \in M_k : \zeta < \xi \implies \overline{G_{\zeta}} \subseteq H^C_{\zeta} \subseteq G_{\xi}.
\end{equation}
For $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and all $\zeta \in M_n$ let the sets $G_{\zeta},H_{\zeta} \in \mathcal{B}$ be defined such that the statement above holds for $k = n$. Now for the induction step let $\zeta \in M_{n+1}$. Then $\zeta$ is of the form $\frac{l}{2^{n+1}}$ for some $l \in \lbrace 0 , \ldots,2^{n+1} \rbrace$. If $l$ is even then $G_{\zeta},H_{\zeta}$ are already defined, since $\zeta \in M_n$. If $l$ is odd then $G_{\zeta},H_{\zeta}$ are not defined yet and
\begin{equation}
M_n \supseteq \zeta' := \frac{l-1}{2^{n+1}} < \zeta < \frac{l+1}{2^{n+1}} =: \zeta'' \in M_n.
\end{equation}
From \eqref{eq:simple} we get $G_{\zeta'} \subseteq H^C_{\zeta'} \subseteq G_{\zeta''}$ hence $H^C_{\zeta'} \cap G^C_{\zeta''} = \emptyset$. Since $\zeta' \neq 1$ we have $H_{\zeta'}$,$G_{\zeta''} \in \mathcal{B}$. Therefore there exists disjoint sets $G_{\zeta},H_{\zeta} \in \mathcal{B}$ with $G_{\zeta} \supseteq H^C_{\zeta'}$ and $H_{\zeta} \supseteq G^C_{\zeta''}$. From this follows $\overline{G_{\zeta'}} \subseteq H^C_{\zeta'} \subseteq G_{\zeta}$ and $\overline{G_{\zeta}}\subseteq H^C_{\zeta} \subseteq G_{\zeta''}$ hence \eqref{eq:simple} holds for $M_{n+1}$. Let $t \in M \setminus \lbrace 1, 0 \rbrace$ where
\begin{equation}
M := \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=0}M_k.
\end{equation}
Then define $O_t := G_t$ and $O_0 := \emptyset$,$O_1 := X$. Now there exists (why?) a continuous function
\begin{equation}
f : \begin{cases}
X \to [0,1] \\
x \mapsto \inf \lbrace r \in M : x \in O_r \rbrace
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
For $x \in A$ we have $x \in G_0$ thus $x \in O_t$ if  $M \supseteq t > 0$. Therefore $f(x) = 0$. Let $\zeta \in M$ then there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $\zeta \in M_k$ meaning $\zeta = \frac{l}{2^k}$ for some $l \in \lbrace 0,\ldots,2^k \rbrace$. Then since
\begin{equation}
\overline{G_{\zeta}} \subseteq H_{\xi}^C \subseteq G_{\xi}
\end{equation}
holds for all $\xi > \zeta$ with $\xi \in M_k$. Since $1 \in M_k$ and $1 > \zeta$ we have
\begin{equation}
G_{\zeta} \subseteq \overline{G_{\zeta}} \subseteq G_{1} = B^C.
\end{equation}
The set $G_1$ is already defined at the start of the induction and is always $B^C$. The only sets that have to be additionaly construct are $H_{\zeta},G_{\zeta}$ for $\zeta \neq 0$ and $\zeta \neq 1$ such that these satisfy the condition \eqref{eq:simple} since those are already defined. So we squeeze those sets $H_{\zeta},G_{\zeta}$ in between.
Hence by construction $G_{\zeta} \subseteq B^C$ for all $\zeta \in M$. For $M \supseteq t < 1$ one has $B \subseteq O_t^C$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in B$ follows.

Finally:

$(iv) \implies (i)$: Let $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a normal (4.2) and weakly regular (4.1) (equivalent to $\forall B \in \mathcal{B} \forall x \in B \exists C \in \mathcal{B} : x \in C^C \subseteq B$) Basis of $\mathcal{T}$ as stated in your $(iv)$ point and $A \subseteq X$ closed with $x \in A^C \in \mathcal{T}$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, there exists a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subseteq A^C$. Also since $\mathcal{B}$ is weakly regular there exists a $C \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in C^C \subseteq B \subseteq A^C$. Since $B$ and $C$ are in $\mathcal{B}$, $C^C$ and $B^C$ disjoint and since $\mathcal{B}$ is a normal basis there exists (why?) a continuous function $f : X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(C^C) \subseteq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $f(B^C) \subseteq \lbrace 1 \rbrace$. From $x \in C^C$ and $A \subseteq B^C$ one gets $f(x) = 0$ and $f(A) \subseteq \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ hence $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is completely regular and $(T_{3.5})$ holds.

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer: thanks very much for it! Unfortunately I am not at home now but do not worry: when I will come back I surely read it with many attention, just give me only some hours.

Comment: If Antonio accepts the answer, you may notify me and I will upvote it.

Comment: The proof is a variant of the Urysohn lemma for normal spaces.

Comment: @Orb Hi, I just a quicked look to your answer but I cannot read accurately it because now I am quite tired (here in Europe is quite late) so that I will study it in the afternoon tomorrow since in the morning I have to run an errand unfortunately. Forgive my delay. Anyway in the meantime you can rearrange the question reordering the passages it if you like. See you soon tomorrow, beye.

Comment: @Orb Hi, I read your (nice) anwer: it seems globally correct to me but  there is something I would like discuss. So I do not understand why by **construction** the inclusion $$G_ζ⊆B^C$$ holds for all $ζ∈M$ so that I thought I misinterpreted what you proposed to your self to prove inductively: thus before to accept it I ask to you if you wanted prove inductively the existence for any $n∈\Bbb N$ of a collection of open sets (**not necessarly** basic!!!) $$\mathfrak F:=\{G_ζ,H_ζ:ζ∈M_n\}$$ of cardinality $n+1$ such that $$ \overline G_ζ⊆H_ζ^C\subseteq G_ξ⊆B^C$$ for any $ζ,ξ∈M_n$ such that $ζ<ξ$.

Comment: So could you explain this, please?

Comment: @Orb Hi, I read your edit: now it is all clear; however I would only like to ask if the density of M follows by the Archimedean property; moreover could you say if I well proved the implication
$$1→2→3→4$$
please? Anyway, thanks very much for your marvelous answer: you were really fantastic. So, question upvoted and approved. Thanks yet.